# heptio velero unable to take backup of persistant volumes in azure AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, backup, azure-aks

i am using 
 - AKS 
 - k8s version 1.12.5
 - Velero version:-  v0.11.0
 - Documents referred from the [link](https://github.com/heptio/velero/blob/master/docs/azure-config.md)

**installed velero on server**

- Install prereq i.e. 00-prereqs.yaml  It installs velero namespace,
  velero service account rbac rules etc.
- Created azure storage account and container
  in it. (i used terraform to create storage account while
  used AZ CLI to create storage container). It is all based on their
  documentation available.
- Created secret.

  *kubectl create secret generic cloud-credentials
   --namespace velero
   --from-literal AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=""
   --from-literal AZURE_TENANT_ID="" 
  --from-literal AZURE_CLIENT_ID="" 
  --from-literal AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="" 
  --from-literal AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP="name-of-resource-group-where-my-vm etc created typically starts with MC_ in azure"*
- applied remaining k8s resources present [at](https://github.com/heptio/velero/tree/master/examples/azure)

**execute backup commands**
[image]

it observed that this command created files for my backup in my storage account as well.
[image]

the similar structure created for other backups as well.

[image]

while checking  pod logs it is observed following information

> time="2019-03-22T14:38:02Z" level=info msg="**Executing takePVSnapshot**"
>   backup=velero/d042203191536 group=v1 groupResource=pods
>   logSource="pkg/backup/item_backupper.go:378"
>   name=pvc-6dd56a3d-4c90-11e9-bc92-1297bc38e414 namespace=default
>   time="2019-03-22T14:38:02Z" level=info msg="label
>   \"**failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone\" is not present on
>   PersistentVolume"**

again

> level=error msg="**Error getting block store for volume snapshot**
>
> time="2019-03-22T14:38:02Z" level=info msg="**PersistentVolume is not a
>   supported volume type for snapshots, skipping**."
>   backup=velero/d042203191536 group=v1 groupResource=pods
>   logSource="pkg/backup/item_backupper.go:436"

and following error as well

> **level=error msg="backup failed" controller=backup
>   error="[clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io
>   \"system:auth-delegator\" not found,**
>   clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io \"system:auth-delegator\" not
>   found]" key=velero/d042203191618
>   logSource="pkg/controller/backup_controller.go:202"

all these logs I observed after executing backup at multiple time intervals

not sure if I am missing anything .any pointers to resolve these problems are really helpful.

Comment: What PV type do you use in your cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Those are currently supported Volume [providers](https://github.com/heptio/velero/pull/723/commits/7edbb91cfa24062104e178247e92e59535d78142)

```
| [Azure Managed Disks][3]         | Ark Team        | [Slack][10], [GitHub Issue][11] |
| [Google Compute Engine Disks][4] | Ark Team        | [Slack][10], [GitHub Issue][11] |
| [Restic][1]                      | Ark Team        | [Slack][10], [GitHub Issue][11] |
| [Portworx][6]                    | PortWorx        |                                 |
| [DigitalOcean][7]                | StackPointCloud |                                 |
```

Make sure  your volume type is compatible with velero plugins